# Help deconstructing a paragraph

Tags: translation

> フィリピンの既婚女性の海外出稼ぎを家族崩壊と結びつけたこの映画は、「女性の海外出稼ぎの
>   社会的コスト」を典型的に指し示すものとして、他方では自分たちのすぐ隣で起こっている物語
>   として、多くのフィリピン人の共感を誘い、国内のみならずフィリピン人の海外出稼ぎ先各国で も上映された。

My translation:

> This film, which ties together already wed Filipino women and the
>   breakdown of the family, points to the typical "the social cost of 
>   migrant working women", on the other hand as a story of our immediate
>   neighbours it inveites us to empathise with many filipinos, not only
>   in our country but in other countries too.

It doesn't make sense atm, but trying to get a whole comprehension on the sentences and can't work it out. Can any help me deconstruct this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic structure is:

> この映画は、多くのフィリピン人の共感を誘い、上映された。
>   This movie raised sympathy of many Filipino, and was screened.

And after adding some modifier clauses:

> ［フィリピンの既婚女性の海外出稼ぎを家族崩壊と結びつけた→］この映画は、〔Aとして、他方ではBとして、→〕多くのフィリピン人の共感を誘い、｛国内のみならずフィリピン人の海外出稼ぎ先各国でも→｝上映された。
>   This movie ［←, which associated emigration of wed Filipino women and the breakdown of their family,］ raised sympathy of many Filipino 〔←(partly) as A, and partly as B〕, and was screened ｛←not only in this country but also in other countries where Filipino work as migrant workers.｝

他方では ("on the other hand") is often used with 一方では, which seems to be omitted in this sentence.

And finally, A and B are the following noun clauses:

> - A: ｛「女性の海外出稼ぎの社会的コスト」を典型的に指し示す→｝もの
> - B: ｛自分たちのすぐ隣で起こっている→｝物語

指し示す in this context is "describe", "symbolize", etc.

Comment: Thanks, I have a translation of:
This movie – which weaved together elements of already wed Filipina working migrants with the collapse of the family – as something that points to the typical “Social cost of women working oversears” and on the other hand as a story of something that happens to one of our closest neighbour invites us to empathise with many of those Filipinos was screened in not only domestically but also countries in which this happens.

Aside from the bad English sentence have I missed anything?

Comment: フィリピン人の共感を誘う is "(the movie) raises the sympathy of/among Filipinos" rather than "(the movie) makes us sympathize with Filipino." This sentence describes why the movie was appreciated also by Filipinos themselves.